# creating blender file using subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python

I am trying to create a blender file using `subprocess.Popen()`. I just cant get it working as I want.

```
test.py

    bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath="C:\\Users\\user.name\\Desktop\\output.blend")
     

subprocess code:

    myargs = [
        "Blender",
         "--python",
         "C:\\Users\\user.name\\Desktop\\test.py"
    ]
        
    subprocess.Popen(myargs)
```

The above code will run and create output.blend ok. But it opens a new file, which I do not want, i want it to run seamlessly in the current instance of blender only. I have tried using -b  and background as well as giving the full blender exe path. But just get the error:

```
    This path does not exist: '.'
    This path does not exist: '.'
    unknown argument, loading as file: --background--python
    Error: Cannot read file 'C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\--background--python': No such file or directory
    Error: argument has no '.blend' file extension, not using as new file, exiting! C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\--background--python
    Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
```

Comment: Isn't the point of Popen to launch a new instance of a program ?

Comment: From what i have read, you can use -b to open it without opening the gui. Popen is opening it, but only in the background.

Comment: I think it does open a new instance of blender, but it doesn't load any UI